# Haskell - What is Control.Applicative.Alternative good for?

Tags: haskell, applicative, alternative-functor

I was looking at the `Applicative` class within Haskell libraries and stumbled across [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2).

What is this class good for? A google search did not reveal anything particularly insightful. And it seems to be completely out of place, bundled as it is with the Applicative package.

Could someone please post a possible scenario where you would use this class?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's commonly used with parser combinators. For example, if `space` is a parser combinator that matches a single whitespace character, `many space` would be one that would match consecutive whitespace.

I can agree that it's slightly out of place in `Control.Applicative`, though.

Comment: Only *slightly* out of place--it's a monoid on `Applicative`s, in the same pattern as `MonadPlus` and `ArrowPlus`, both of which also share a module with the class they're based on. For consistency it "should" have been called `ApplicativePlus` but that's an ugly name.

Comment: Okay that explains a lot! Though naming `ApplicativePlus` to `Alternative` isn't such a good thing since the latter has connotations that limit its scope.

Comment: @C. A. McCann, I wish you would convert your comment into an answer so I could accept it :)

Comment: @Anupam Jain: Eh, I think it's fine as is. hammar already covered the part about where it's actually used and I don't feel like reiterating that to make a complete answer...

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes the `<|>` operator is quite useful:

```
foldl1 (<|>) [Nothing, Just 5, Just 3]
-- Just 5
```

Comment: Ah that is interesting! In that context <|> is like the short circuit || operator in many imperative languages..

Comment: You can also do this using `mconcat` with [the `First` monoid](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t:First). This generalizes nicely to [the other `Maybe` monoids](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/monoids-for-maybe/).

Comment: Oh, no, `foldl1` was used somewhere where there is a sensible default (`foldl (<|>) Nothing`). What will you do when your answer crashes? :D

Comment: @Rotsor or `foldl (<|>) empty` in general, given that `empty` is the identity of `(<|>)`

Comment: In general, ```Data.Foldable.asum``` also provides this functionality